# Best 3rd-party Library for iOS Parallax Effect?

Tags: ios, parallax

I'm currently using APParallaxHeader, but unfortunately it has a section header bug (gets left behind on upward scroll), and doesn't work correctly with landscape or ipad resizing. There are so many libraries out there (not sure if this is the correct term), but I was wondering if any of you have tried one that uses the objective-c runtime and works correctly without different orientations.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried tried this one...

https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/BBInfiniteView

Comment: Have you? No point in linking otherwise so make it clear.